# How to create instance by string Array?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, generics

I have 15 string value. For example: excel sheet names: Customers, Products etc. these sheet,s names are the same as db Tables also Ef 4.0 Entities Name. (Products.cs, Customers.cs)

```
String[] excelSheets = GetExcelSheetNames(String.Format(@"C:\{0}\{1}", UserName, FileUploadForExcel.FileName));
foreach (String excelSheet in excelSheets)
 {
      GetEntity(excelSheet);
 }

protected TModel GetEntity(string ClassNameFromExcelSheetName)
{
   return(TModel)Activator.CreateInstance(ClassNameFromExcelSheetName);
}
```

above code is a kind of simple foresight. NOT real codes. How to create instance  only using string value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create instance of class by class name in string representation using .NET Reflection

Check the following article on reflection:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Reflection.aspx

```
System.Reflection.Assembly assem = Assembly.Load("");

object thisObj = assem.CreateInstance("Customers");
foreach (PropertyInfo pi in thisObj.GetType().GetProperties)
{
   // List all properties in object 
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably could use some kind of Factory design pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create these instances yourself, perhaps using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/).

Comment: it must be too simple not need to use dll